# Can Nikon Nikorr 50/1.4D be used with a Nikon FM2?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, film-cameras

I plan to obtain  [Nikon Nikorr 50/1.4D](https://images.app.goo.gl/VunvnrZRTJMeJZoL7). Can it be used for Nikon FM2?

Is it an AiS lens? I read somewhere that non AiS Lens may damage FM2.

Comment: Yes, all Nikon lenses designated AF (with or without D), as long as they have no G or E in their name (excepting Series E lenses, which is a different E) are Ai-S lenses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia *FM2* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_FM2):

> The FM2 accepts all Nikon F bayonet mount lenses that support the Automatic Indexing (AI) feature introduced in 1977. The Nikon-made AI lenses of this type are the AF-S Nikkor, AF-I Nikkor, AF Nikkor D, AF Nikkor, Nikkor AI-S, Nikkor AI and Nikon Series E types. Nikon’s most recent 35 mm film SLR lenses, the AF Nikkor G type (introduced in 2000) and the AF Nikkor DX type (2003) will mount but will not function properly.

Non AI-S lenses are those made (or designed) before 1977 and does not include any Nikkor 'D' lenses.

There's a little more information regarding this on page 50 of the [*FM2 User's Manual*](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/archive/FM2.pdf). The *Manual* doesn't mention 'D' lenses such as the AF-S Nikkor 50mm f/1.4D because they did not exist yet when the manual was written.

[image]